# Localize flash messages?

Tags: localization, laravel-5, sweetalert

Please advise how to localize flash messages? I followed laracast series: https://laracasts.com/series/build-project-flyer-with-me/episodes/9

```
    Auth::login(User::firstOrCreate($data));

    flash()->success('flash.success', 'flash.login');
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return redirect('/login')->with('status', trans('auth.registered'));
```

In resources/lang/es/auth.php

```
return [
     ...
     'registered' => "Your message translated on Spanish.",
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through about localization [Laravel Localization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization)

You can find more information

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

in your controller

```
return redirect('/login')->with('success', __('auth.registered'));
```

and in lang files for example using **En** and **Ar**

go to `lang/en/auth` and create your status message

```
'registered' => 'Your message in English'
```

go to `lang/ar/auth` and create your status message

```
'registered' => 'Your message in Arabic'
```

then in your blade, you retrieve the coming message from the controller

```
@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <div class="alert-body">
            {{session('success')}}
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```